# How to override existing react-native native components

Tags: ios, react-native

There is `MapView` module in react-native. (`RCTMapManager` module)

It currently doesn't support custom view for annotations. Is it possible to override `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(__unused MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(RCTPointAnnotation *)annotation` method in custom bridge? 
Or I have to create my own `RCTMapManager` component from scratch

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create you own `RCTMapManager` component from scratch. The best way to solve this in your use case would be to

1. Copy the existing implementation (& rename it)
2. Implement the custom views for annotations (and use it in your project)
3. Fork React-Native & Do a pull request for the custom views for annotations